# Aerospike process taking lot of memory

Tags: linux, ram, aerospike

Aerospike Community Edition build 3.12.0

We have a cluster of 32 nodes with one namespace having multiple sets. I see following in logs:

> Sep 29 2018 15:36:21 GMT+0530: INFO (info): (ticker.c:462) {myNamespace} memory-usage: total-bytes 23816040182 index-bytes 3222810368 sindex-bytes 0 data-bytes 20593229814 used-pct 49.29
>
> Sep 29 2018 15:36:21 GMT+0530: INFO (info): (ticker.c:170) NODE-ID bb99a89200a0102 CLUSTER-SIZE 32
>
> Sep 29 2018 15:36:21 GMT+0530: INFO (info): (ticker.c:253)    system-memory: free-kbytes 5095788 free-pct 9 heap-kbytes (30851170,49358076,52596736) heap-efficiency-pct 58.7
>
> Sep 29 2018 15:36:21 GMT+0530: INFO (info): (ticker.c:267)    in-progress: tsvc-q 0 info-q 0 nsup-delete-q 0 rw-hash 0 proxy-hash 0 tree-gc-q 0

So what I understand is this has (23816040182+3222810368) = 27038850550 bytes [i.e.](https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=RVSvW9fQDseBvgSNoLngAg&q=27038850550+bytes+to+gb&oq=27038850550+bytes+to+gb&gs_l=psy-ab.3...65669.65669.0.66007.1.1.0.0.0.0.91.91.1.1.0....0...1c.2.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.62xE1BOoh6k) 27G. I have 52G RAM on the box, but the aerospike process is consuming 90% of RAM:

```
>ps aux  | grep asd
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND    
root     28994 14.3 90.5 59059460 49552192 ?   Ssl  Jun22 20539:09 /usr/bin/asd --config-file /etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf


>free -mh
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           52G        51G       303M         0B        12M       3.7G
-/+ buffers/cache:        48G       4.0G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

For the same node I see following in UI:

[image]

So, Data + index  is only 27G, while memory used is 49G. Not able to understand this huge different and how to avoid such scenarios.

We also deleted some 120 million rows, but still not much improvement in terms of memory usage, only option seems to restart the box, This might be related to this [issue](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/cluster-ram-still-in-use-after-all-records-deleted/1522/9).

Answer (score 2):

Seems your memory is actually fragmented, but let's break down the different numbers:

1- `memory-usage: total-bytes 23816040182 index-bytes 3222810368 sindex-bytes 0 data-bytes 20593229814 used-pct 49.29`

The total memory accounted for is 23816040182 bytes (~22.18 GiB), which is the sum of what you have in the primary index 3222810368 (50,356,412 records at 64 bytes each) and what the data itself (as you are data in memory) which is 20593229814 (~19.2 GiB). The primary index portion is in shared memory.

2- `system-memory: free-kbytes 5095788 free-pct 9 heap-kbytes (30851170,49358076,52596736) heap-efficiency-pct 58.7`

The free system memory reported is not accurate in version 3.12. You unfortunately have less available (see fix [AER-5810] - (STATS) Log ticker over-reports free system memory available in version 3.16.0.4).

More interesting is the heap usage, (from the [log reference manual](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/serverlogmessages/)) which you can read as:

- heap-kbytes - in order: ([heap_allocated_kbytes](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#heap_allocated_kbytes), [heap_active_kbytes](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#heap_active_kbytes), [heap_mapped_kbytes](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#heap_mapped_kbytes)).
- heap-efficiency-pct: Provides an indication of the jemalloc heap fragmentation. This represents the heap_allocated_kbytes / heap_mapped_kbytes ratio. A lower number indicates a higher fragmentation rate.

You have 30851170 KiB allocated (~29.4 GiB) but a total of 52596736 KiB (~50.1 GiB mapped) and this is not efficient (58.7% efficiency) indicating some fragmentation. This does not include the shared memory by the way. 29 GiB allocated seems a bit high for 19 GiB of data. I would have expected less overhead for all the other internal structures used.

The main issue is the inefficiency, though, the fragmentation. Do you have THP enabled by any chance? I actually found this article ([Understanding Linux Memory Usage](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/understanding-linux-memory-usage-reporting/4727)) which also goes through those memory reporting details and goes through the Huge Pages config as well which may be causing this.